rego language multiple rules in same violation
These are rules that are part of a
apiVersion: templates.gatekeeper.sh/v1
kind: ConstraintTemplate

Can you help me understand why this works (preventing the creation of deployments out of the limits):
package minmaxreplicasreplicaset

violation[{"msg": msg}] {
  replicas := input.review.object.spec.replicas
  min :=input.parameters.min
  max := input.parameters.max
  not (replicas > min)
  msg := sprintf("replicas %v not between %v %v", [replicas, min, max])
}  

violation[{"msg": msg}] {
  replicas := input.review.object.spec.replicas
  min :=input.parameters.min
  max := input.parameters.max
  not (replicas < max)
  msg := sprintf("replicas %v not between %v %v", [replicas, min, max])
}  

while this (with both boundaries combined) do not:
package minmaxreplicasreplicaset

violation[{"msg": msg}] {
  replicas := input.review.object.spec.replicas
  min :=input.parameters.min
  max := input.parameters.max
  not (replicas > min)
  not (replicas < max)
  msg := sprintf("replicas %v not between %v %v", [replicas, min, max])
}  


Combined in the same violation, unless min is equal to max, one of the two conditions – not (replicas > min), not (replicas < max) – would always be false, and thus blocking the violation from triggering.
As an example, say we have

replicas == 10
min == 1
max == 3

Then

not (replicas > min) => not (10 > 1) => false (then the violation won't trigger)
not (replicas < max) => not (10 < 3) => true.

Now, as a count example, let's say min and max are the same as before, but replicas == 0. Then

not (replicas > min) => not (0 > 1) => true
not (replicas < max) => not (0 < 3) => false  (then the violation won't trigger).

